# What does this ocaml snippet mean?

Tags: ocaml

```
let memorize o table = Hashtbl.add table (o :> < >) o
```

`:>` is cast, but I don't understand the `< >` in it..

Answer (score 2):

So `< ... >` is the syntax for object types in OCaml. The methods go inside the `<` and `>`. `< >` is object type that specifies no methods; thus any object type can be upcasted into this type. This type is normally pretty useless, since you cannot really do anything with a value of this type (since there is no downcasting of object types in OCaml, you can never make it into something you can call a method on).

In this case, they are using this as the key type of the hash table. I do not really know why they are doing this.

Answer (score 1):

`< mi: ti>` is the type of an object having methods `mi` with type `ti`. Here, you are coercing `o` into an object without any method, that is the supertype of all object types (akin to `Object` in Java). In other words, the table is supposed to be able to store any object.